# Webpack configuration for react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm a newbie to react and webpack. Im trying to understand how does it affect a react app with or without webpack configuration or is it mandatory?

Comment: If you're just starting out learning javascript, React and Redux is not for you. If you really want to, check out the tutorials on React's website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to understand what webpack is, and what it does.

Wepack is a bundling utility. This means you can have a bunch of different files, (doesn't necessarily have to be javascript, you can have css, sass, images, etc.) and it will bundle them together into one package. This is necessary when working with react because you can develop your application with many different files, use modern syntax structures such as `import` and `=>` and everything gets delivered in one package (though there are many great options to split this code into smaller bundles).

So long story short, you can do React without webpack, but it is much easier to use webpack. In fact, many react projects are developed using a webpack server, which live bundles everything as you write your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation